# Linux bluetooth device - configure as serial port

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port

I have a particular sensor that communicates in the following manner:

IR - IR - FTDI UART - USB - Computer

This comes up as a serial port - /dev/ttyUSB0. That works fine.

The sensor also has an optional bluetooth backpack which communicates as follows:

IR - IR - Bluetooth - Computer

I've paired the bluetooth backpack, but my question, how do I allocate that to a serial port? It does not by default come up as /dev/rfcom*

There's a variety of forum posts on similar topics, but no clear instructions on how to actually do it.

tried:

```
sudo rfcomm connect rfcomm0 54:4D:4F:00:50:34
```

but get:

```
Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Connection refused
```

hcitool -

```
sudo hcitool scan
```

gives:

```
Scanning ...
Inquiry failed: Operation not supported
```

The command

```
sdptool browse 54:4D:4F:00:50:34
```

returns

```
Failed to connect to SDP server on 54:4D:4F:00:50:34: Connection refused
```

Its a thermofisher RadEye Bluetooth adapter.

So in [the manual](https://assets.thermofisher.com/TFS-Assets%2FLSG%2Fbrochures%2FD16620%7E.pdf), pairing requires a pass code. This behaviour is present when I pair to my phone. It doesn't however show up on Linux. The device just connects. That could be the source of the connection refused.

The device is paired though. It shows as connected. Other devices will ask for a PIN but for some reason under Ubuntu, it just connects to it without a pin (In dual or LE mode, not bredr). Either solution would work fine, CLI or GUI.